# Bash line causing some kind of recursion with ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I have the following line in a bash boot script:

`declare -fx $(bash -c "source ~/.local/bash.d/functions/10-git.bash &> /dev/null; compgen -A function")`

I get no errors when firing up bash locally but when I ssh in from another machine, it causes a bunch of errors:

```
Last login: Fri Jan 31 09:25:00 2020
5.0.7(1)-release
/Users/me/.local/bash.d/exports/10-git.bash: cannot make pipe for command substitution: Too many open files
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc: cannot make pipe for command substitution: Too many open files
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc: cannot make pipe for command substitution: Too many open files
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc: cannot make pipe for command substitution: Too many open files
/Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc: line 19: cannot create temp file for here-document: Too many open files
/Users/me/.bashrc: line 8: read: read error: 0: Bad file descriptor
/Users/me/.bashrc: line 7: sort: command not found
/Users/me/.bashrc: line 7: find: command not found
/Users/me/.local/bash.d/exports/10-git.bash: line 10: declare: cannot use `-f' to make functions
Can't locate warnings/register.pm:   Too many open files at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/vars.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/vars.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Config.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Config.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew line 3.
```

I'm guessing it's causing some kind of recursion but I'm unclear why this only happens when I ssh into the machine. Is there anything I can do prevent the errors?

Comment: Checking your PATHs may help. Its possible you are setting a path in your non-login shell somewhere in /etc/bashrc for instance, which isn't carrying over when using a login shell, even though your login shell is including the non-login startup script in ~/.bashrc

Comment: Consider sharing the file '10-git.bash', and the bash ersion for the remote and local machines.

Comment: The command I showed is all that is in the 10-git.bash file. Bash version are 5.09 on client and 5.07 on server.

Comment: To get a detailed output of what bash is doing, you can use `bash -x`. It might be interesting to know what you mean by "bash boot script".